# Convert Excel 'if' function to SQL query

Tags: sql, excel

I have a function like this:

`if(a>b,if(b>c,a,b),c)`

This follows the syntax `if(condition,true,false)`. I was looking for a way to convert this into an SQL query like so:

```
select case 
  when a>b then 
     case 
          when b>c then a 
          else b 
     end 
  else c 
end
```

I thought of splitting the input and passing it on my own, but I was hoping there was a better way to do this.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IIF function as well... Please check the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) for description.

So for you it would be something like SELECT IIF (a > b, IIF ( B > C, A, B ), C ) AS Result;

Sytax is not tested but would work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one doubt though, does it support nesting of `IIF` statements?

Comment: Just checked online and it does support nesting! Thanks once again!

Comment: `IIF` is available from SQL Server 2012 onwards. Is there an equivalent statement in SQL Server 2008?